# Clojure function to Replace Count

Tags: clojure

I need help with an assignment that uses Clojure. It is very small but the language is a bit confusing to understand. I need to create a function that behaves like count without actually using the count funtion. I know a loop can be involved with it somehow but I am at a lost because nothing I have tried even gets my code to work. I expect it to output the number of elements in list. For example:

```
(defn functionname []
...
...)

(println(functionname '(1 4 8)))
```

### Output:3

Here is what I have so far:

```
(defn functionname [n]
(def n 0)
  (def x 0)
  (while (< x n)
    do 
    ()
    )
)

(println(functionname '(1 4 8)))
```

It's not much but I think it goes something like this.

Comment: Please add your implementation of `functionname` to the question.

Comment: `functionname` is the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation takes the first element of the list and runs a sum until it can't anymore and then returns the sum.

```
(defn recount [list-to-count]
 (loop [xs list-to-count sum 0]
   (if (first xs)
     (recur (rest xs) (inc sum))
     sum
)))
```

```
user=> (recount '(3 4 5 9))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more example implementations:

```
(defn not-count [coll]
  (reduce + (map (constantly 1) coll)))
```

or:

```
(defn not-count [coll]
  (reduce (fn [a _] (inc a)) 0 coll))
```

or:

```
(defn not-count [coll]
  (apply + (map (fn [_] 1) coll)))
```

result:

```
(not-count '(5 7 8 1))
=> 4
```

I personally like the first one with `reduce` and `constantly`.